# GmailApp.search doesn't filter the labels

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to send the all attachments to my Google Drive account but I have problem with the search of GmailApp.search.

I have a Camera in my home that sends an email every 5 minutes with the same Subject and each message has an attached file that's name is the day-time.jpg

First I think in search by label and then of the process, I put a new label to mark and don't repeat the message, but I always receive all the message.

I tried to test many ways and always received the message that has label:processed.

```
function () {
  //All message of the camera have the label GoogleDrive
  var threads = GmailApp.search("has:attachment -label:processed label:GoogleDrive", 0, 5);  
  var folder = getFolder(driveFolder);

  for (var x=0; x<threads.length; x++) {
    var message = threads[x].getMessages();  

    for(var y=0; y<message.length; y++) {
      var desc   = message[y].getSubject() + " #" + message[y].getId();
      var att    = message[y].getAttachments();


      for (var z=0; z<att.length; z++) {
        try {        
          if (check) {
            var name = att[z].getName();
            if (name.indexOf(".") != -1) {
              var extn = name.substr(name.lastIndexOf(".")+1).toLowerCase();
              if (valid.indexOf(extn) != -1) {
                file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
                file.setDescription(desc);
              } else {
                Logger.log("Skipping " + name);
              }
            }
          } else {
            file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
            file.setDescription(desc);
          }  
        }
        catch (e) {
          Logger.log(e.toString());
        }
      }
    }
    threads[x].addLabel(moveToLabel); //this variable is processed label
  }
}
```

Regards

---

I have this function. I use the ctrlq.org code as base, only I put the principal function.

Now I copy all the script

```
    function createFilter(label, archiveLabel) {

  var filter = "has:attachment -label:" + archiveLabel + " label:" + label;  

  return filter;

}


function help() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('help')
  .setTitle("Google Scripts Support")
  .setWidth(400)
  .setHeight(260);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.show(html);
}


function premium() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Upgrade to the <a href="www.labnol.org/internet/send-gmail-to-google-drive/21236/#premium">premium edition of Send to Google Drive</a> and unlock new features. You can also opt for one-on-one support via email, Skype or Google Hangouts.')
  .setTitle("Send to Google Drive Premium")
  .setWidth(240)
  .setHeight(100);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.show(html);
}


function sendToGoogleDrive() { 

  var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var gmailLabels  = sheet.getRange("D4:D4").getValue();  
  var driveFolder  = sheet.getRange("D5:D5").getValue();  
  var archiveLabel = sheet.getRange("D6:D6").getValue();
  var filetypes    = sheet.getRange("D7:D7").getValue();

  var valid = filetypes.replace(/\s/g,"").toLowerCase().split(",");
  var check = true;

  if ( (valid.indexOf("all") != -1) || (valid.length == 1 && valid[0] == "")) {
    check = false;
  }

  var moveToLabel = getGmailLabel(archiveLabel);

  var filter = createFilter(gmailLabels, archiveLabel);
  var threads = GmailApp.search(filter, 0, 5);  
  var folder = getFolder(driveFolder);

  sheet.getRange("D9:D9").setValue(sheet.getRange("D9:D9").getValue() + ", [th(" + threads.length + ")");

  for (var x=0; x<threads.length; x++) {
    var message = threads[x].getMessages();  
  sheet.getRange("D9:D9").setValue(sheet.getRange("D9:D9").getValue() + ", ms(" + message.length + ")");    
    for(var y=0; y<message.length; y++) {
      var desc   = message[y].getSubject() + " #" + message[y].getId();
      var att    = message[y].getAttachments();

  //sheet.getRange("D9:D9").setValue(sheet.getRange("D9:D9").getValue() + ", at(" + att.length + ")");    
      for (var z=0; z<att.length; z++) {
        try {        
          if (check) {
            var name = att[z].getName();
            if (name.indexOf(".") != -1) {
              var extn = name.substr(name.lastIndexOf(".")+1).toLowerCase();
              if (valid.indexOf(extn) != -1) {
                file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
                file.setDescription(desc);
              } else {
                Logger.log("Skipping " + name);
              }
            }
          } else {
            file = folder.createFile(att[z]);
            file.setDescription(desc);
          }  
        }
        catch (e) {
          Logger.log(e.toString());
        }
      }
    }
    threads[x].moveToTrash();
    threads[x].addLabel(moveToLabel);
  }
  sheet.getRange("D9:D9").setValue(sheet.getRange("D9:D9").getValue() + "]");

}


function configure() {

  reset(true);

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendToGoogleDrive").timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();

  Browser.msgBox("Initialized", "The program is now running. You can close this sheet", Browser.Buttons.OK);

}

function init() {
  return;
}

function onOpen() {  
  var menu = [    
    {name: "Help and Support »",functionName: "help"},
    null,
    { name: "Step 1: Authorize",   functionName: "init"      },
    { name: "Step 2: Run Program", functionName: "configure" },
    null,
    { name: "Uninstall (Stop)",    functionName: "reset"     },
    null,
    {name: "Upgrade to Premium »",functionName: "premium"},
    null
  ];  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .addMenu("Gmail Attachments", menu);
}

function getFolder(parent) {

  var parentFolder, searchFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(parent);

  if (searchFolder.hasNext()) {
    parentFolder = searchFolder.next();
  } else {
    parentFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(parent);
  }

  return parentFolder;

}


function getGmailLabel(name) {

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);

  if ( ! label ) {

    label = GmailApp.createLabel(name);

  }

  return label;

}

function reset(e) {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);    
  }

  if (!e) {
    Browser.msgBox("Script Stopped", "You can start the script anytime later!", Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }

}
```

My inbox have these mails:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq1Ws.png)

The problem is then I run the script the mail has a new label (now I send to Trash too), but in the next run the GmailApp.Search, find the mail that have processed label.

I copy the configuration sheet

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2k0O.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have not defined moveToLabel and hence the same set of Gmail threads are getting processed in each loop.

Add this line before the for loop.

```
  var moveToLabel =  GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("processed");

  if ( ! moveToLabel ) {    
    moveToLabel = GmailApp.createLabel(processed);    
  }
```

You can get the full snippet at [ctrlq.org](http://ctrlq.org/code/19053-send-to-google-drive).